# Repositioning scrolled list to place a newly created item at the top

Tags: python, tkinter

My model is a list of more or less complex objects. My view displays a list of rows, one per object. Each row show a couple of identifying properties of the corresponding object. The list is long, so I have a scrollbar.

To edit one object, the user clicks on the corresponding row and the row "expands" into an editor (which is still part of the list of rows). I.e., I'm not popping up a dialog box but just replacing the simple row with a more complex widget.

The way I do this is to grid.forget the old widget, create the editor widget and .grid in the same row. This works without problem.

In addition to this, I want to ensure that the editor widget is completely visible (even when, say, the row was very low in the window). To do this, I want to scroll the list so the editor widget is at the top of the visible region. This is some pseudo-code:

```
# find the clicked row
...

# get rid of the old widget
w = self.widgets[row]
w.grid_forget()
w.destroy()

# create the editor widget and .grid it in place
w = Editor(...)
w.grid(row=row, ...)

# find the editor y-position and scroll so that it is on
# the upper edge of the viewing area
y = w.winfo_y()
scrollcanvas.yview('moveto', 0.0)
scrollcanvas.yview('scroll', y, 'units') # units are pixels
```

This does not work. When I print y I get zero. I believe this is because
the position returned by winfo_y has not (yet) been updated because Tkinter updates those things asynchronously. But I don't know what to do about it except some disgusting hack such as finding y as the position of the previous row plus its height (aaaak!!!)

Would delaying the scrolling to the editor 'Configure' event help?

Comment: Have you tried a `root.after(1, scrollfunction)` where `scrollfunction` is a function (either named or anonymous) that scrolls to the top of the list?

Comment: No. I don't like the idea of waiting for a set amount of time in order for things to stabilize. I'd prefer to wait until some event occurs that guarantees that the info I need is stable. I mean, I believe your suggestion would work, but why 1sec, why not 0.001secs? What is a 'safe' amount of time? I hate race conditions.

Comment: That's not 1 second, it's 1 millisecond (the minimum value). ["This method registers a callback function that will be called after a given number of milliseconds. Tkinter only guarantees that the callback will not be called earlier than that; if the system is busy, the actual delay may be much longer."](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) I don't think it's actually a race condition.

Comment: `y` will probably be zero until the UI has had a chance to actually draw the widget on the screen. You can call `update_idletasks`, or try what @TigerhawkT3 suggests and use `after` to run the command a millisecond after the event loop has had a chance to process redraw events.

Comment: I'll look into that, Bryan. Sorry, TigerhawkT3, I misinterpreted the '1'. But actually Tkinter does not guarantee much: "if the system is busy it may take much longer". Sure. Long enough for y to be stable? Why do you think it isn't a race condition?